# Trying to set up a zapier webhook to pabau CRM error

Tags: facebook, zapier

I'm trying to set up a webhook with zapier to take leads from facebook forms, and pass them to my CRM system Pabau. I have set it up as instructed in this link - https://intercom.help/pabau/en/articles/3847411-create-lead-api

It's not passing the leads through, although facebook is working and integrated properly with full admin access and set up correctly with the crm added to the bm.

It's showing a fault code as api key error but there are no other options with Pabau to change this and I tried different keys.

[Fault error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MV03.png)

I have tried everything and both zapier and pabau support teams cannot advise on the issue. any help would be greatly appreciated,

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get Api_key
[image]

1. create api key
   [image]
2. then give it the right premissions
   [image]

and make sure to add the new created api key to post data on zapier weebhooks

[image]

request failed because api key is required

pabau docs

[image]